# Lock file permanently as read-only in Writer

Tags: openoffice, read-only, file-permissions

Is it possible to lock a file in OpenOffice.org Writer permanently? Giving it a "read only" status forever?

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible from within OpenOffice. You can however change access rights for the file in the file system (file properties in Windows, file permissions for Linux etc.) to make the file readonly.

This is forever in the sense that it will last until someone changes it.